# Can Haproxy use endpoint to determine load balancing?

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible for haproxy to ask a (REST http) Endpoint to determine, if a specific server is available for loadbalancing?

See example below for our setup. If 'a' is down, the haproxy 'ha' should not use the way over 'x'.

```
   x--a
  /    \
ha      out
  \    / 
   y--b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have to have a page to return the HTTP status, and HAProxy will use it to determine the status.

For example:

```
backend web-backend
    option      httpchk HEAD /status.php
    server      servera servera check inter 2s rise 1 fall 2
    server      serverb serverb check inter 2s rise 1 fall 2
```

Comment: Further doc: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-option%20httpchk